# How to block user input entirely in C++ (UNIX)

Tags: c++, unix, input, cin

I'm working on a project where I want to have delays in the output in C++ on UNIX. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
cout << "You walk through the darkness, no sign of life in sight" << endl;
usleep(1000000);
cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
cin >> userCommand;
```

Now, if the user types something while the usleep is ongoing, it goes into the cin statement later, which, while I can give appropriate error messages, I'd rather not deal with. Additionally, sometimes I want certain things on the screen, so I don't want the user to just hold down enter and clear the screen.

Is there any command which fully blocks user input from even interacting with the screen? Something that I could deactivate right before my cin statement and reactivate right after the cin statement?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you don't want your program to be a consol based one...

Comment: Simple. After `usleep`, just clear all waiting characters with `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());` See [std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

Comment: You probably want to use [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), which gives much more control over the terminal window than provided by the C++ library.

Comment: possible duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282388/stopping-the-user-from-entering-letters-c

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried doing that already, but I found that it does not continue the program unless the user presses enter. Correction: std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n') does not work until the user presses enter. I tried std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()) and found that it just stops the program forever (or rather until the player types in the maximum amount of characters).

Comment: @Eljay Just took a look at ncurses, seems like it could be pretty good, but for this specific project, I'd rather not have to deal with anything that requires me to mess with the compiling of it or anything like that. But it does look good, I'll probably look into it more and use that for later projects, so thanks!

Comment: @Whiteshadow64 - you are correct hat if there is nothing waiting and you use the `'\n'` as the delimiter, it will wait for a newline. Remove the `'\n'` entirely and let it default to `.eof()`. You can also use `cin.peek()` to check if there is input waiting before calling `.ignore`.

Answer (score -2):

you can use

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
cout << "You walk through the darkness, no sign of life in sight" << endl;
getch();
cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
cin >> userCommand;
```

getch() block until you press a key

Comment: Yes... but that isn't the issue he is addressing. `getch()` (despite being 100% non-portable), would not solve the issue.